# :focus not working - I've used it this way before! CSS/HTML

Tags: html, css

I've got a menu where :focus isn't working on the divs that have a tabindex set.

Here's the layout of the HTML

```
<header>
<nav>
<div class="nav-link one" tabindex="1"><a href="#index">Home</a></div>
<div class="nav-link two" tabindex="2"><a href="#services">Services</a></div>
<div class="nav-link three" tabindex="3"><a href="#info">Info</a></div>
<div class="nav-link four" tabindex="4"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></div>
</nav>
</header>
```

Heres the CSS:

```
nav .nav-link a {
font-family: 'majalla'; 
font-size:3em;
display: block;
float: left;
width: auto;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
padding: 8px 20px;
margin: 0px 0px;
border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
/* border-right: 1px solid white; */
border-left: 2px solid rgb(247, 247, 247);
text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(144, 141, 141, 1);
}
nav .nav-link:focus a, nav .nav-link:hover a {
background-color: rgba(155, 155, 155, 0.2);
border-left: 2px solid rgb(47, 32, 21);
text-decoration:none;
}
```

I don't know what i'm missing, :hover is working but not :focus. It's almost like i can't focus on the div with tabindex set.

Check it out live here: www.jessemspears.com

Is there something else i should use?

Edit:
I can TAB to it just fine, but clicking it should focus on it too like it does here: http://jessemspears.com/indexv2.php | click one of the letters. 
(this is an old mess of code i pulled out to show you guys)

Comment: @dwreck08 he gave it that ability by giving it a tabindex. It works for me on Chrome though. I can tab through them and they act the same as if they are hovered.

Comment: What browser are you experiencing the problem in?

Comment: Read my edit, tabing works fine but clicking on it should activate the :focus.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get your meaning that what results you want. However, I have made some changes for you, the button will keep the style after clicking on it. Do you want this result below?

```css
nav .nav-link a {
 font-family: 'majalla'; 
 font-size:3em;
 display: block;
 float: left;
 width: auto;
 text-align: center;
 vertical-align: middle;
 padding: 8px 20px;
    margin: 0px 0px;
 border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
 /* border-right: 1px solid white; */
 border-left: 2px solid rgb(247, 247, 247);
 text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(144, 141, 141, 1);
}
nav .nav-link a:focus, nav .nav-link a:hover {
 background-color: rgba(155, 155, 155, 0.2);
 border-left: 2px solid rgb(47, 32, 21);
 text-decoration:none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>
  <header>
    <nav>
      <div class="nav-link one" tabindex="1"><a href="#index">Home</a></div>
      <div class="nav-link two" tabindex="2"><a href="#services">Services</a></div>
      <div class="nav-link three" tabindex="3"><a href="#info">Info</a></div>
      <div class="nav-link four" tabindex="4"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></div>
     </nav>
  </header>
</html>
```

Hope this can help you ;)